# Append dataframe to a specified existing column

Tags: python, pandas

I'am writing a code that requires appending a dataframe to include the new data to a specific column

Here is an extract of the code as below.

Descriptive summary of the code:

1. I have two variables (i and j) that I want to copy to a pandas dataframe.
2. I started by creating an empty dataframe with column names (4 columns in total)
3. Once the variables (i and j) are calculated in the for loop, i want to copy them to the dataframe into their respective columns(i_col and j_col, respectively)
4. Iam getting an error in the hashtagged code line (df=df.append.....)

   import pandas as pd

   df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['i_column','j_column','type','Location',])

   for i in range (1,10):

   ```
   i=3+i

   print (i)

   #df = df.append([i], column=['i_column'])
   ```

   for j in range (5,12):
       j=j+5

   ```
   print (j)

   #df = df.append([j],column=['j_column'])
   ```

   print (df)

Currently I'am getting this error:
TypeError: append() got an unexpected keyword argument 'column'

Instead i want to append the dataframe with i values in the i_column and j values in the j_column. Please advise the correct code line for it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something like this?

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

columns = ['col_i', 'col_j', 'col_notused', 'col_alsonotused']

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
vals_i = [1,2,3]
vals_j = [2,3,1]

for index, (i, j) in enumerate(zip(vals_i, vals_j)):
    df_temp = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
    df_temp.loc[index] = (i, j, np.nan, np.nan)
    df = df.append(df_temp)

print(df)

Output:
   col_i  col_j  col_notused  col_alsonotused
0    1.0    2.0          NaN              NaN
1    2.0    3.0          NaN              NaN
2    3.0    1.0          NaN              NaN
```

Comment: Is there another way to do it through the append dataframe code line (df.appened(..)) i need this for another long code where appending would make things much simpler. Please help.

Comment: I modified my answer. Hopefully this is what you are looking for.

Comment: If you have no values for specific columns, you could simply add `np.NaN`s at their place. I modified my answer again to account for that.

Comment: No but this is an answer that i found that worked (FYI):  df = df.append({'j_column':j},ignore_index=True)